# How do I slice an array by index in julia

Tags: julia

So say 
a=[[1 2];[3 4];[5 6]]
and x is [1,2,1]
how would I extract the vector [1,4,5]; that is, the index-x element of each row.

Comment: [a[i,x[i]] for i in 1:size(a)[1]] works for example, but seems unjuliiaic.

Comment: or `getindex.(eachrow(a), x)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use broadcasting. Use `Ref(a)` to avoid broadcasting over `a`:

```
julia>  getindex.(Ref(a),1:length(x),x)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 4
 5
```

Comment: Super, alternatively per a reply on reddit: getindex.(eachrow(a), x[:])

Comment: @conor It should be `x`, not `x[:]`. The latter would create an unnecessary copy.